# Why this piecewise function doesn't have a removable discontinuity?

Tags: calculus, continuity, piecewise-continuity

In the third function from this image. The function when $x$ is not equal to $2$ can be transformed into $ x+1 $, resulting in having a value of $3$ at the point $ x = 2 $.

Why is this not considered a removable discontinuity?

[image]

Comment: Essentially what the answer states is that the hole has been filled in by the piecewise part.

Comment: A removed discontinuity is not removable, because there's nothing more to remove :(

Answer (score 4):

It is because

$f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{x^2-x-2}{x-2}; x\ne 2\\ 3; x=2\end{cases}$

is continuous at $x=2$ (Note that $\lim _{x\to 2} f(x)=\lim_{x\to 2}(x+1)=3$ and $f(2)=3$) and as per the given question, you are required to choose functions which have a **removable discontinuity** at $x=2$.